# Phpquery dom parser changing the contents inside the script tag

Tags: phpquery

Phpquery dom parser changing contents inside the javascript tags. I use following code

```
$pq         = phpQuery::newDocument($html);//$html -> grab the page using curl
echo $pq->html();
```

**Actuall browser page view source**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div-id').append(
           '<div class="tool">'
                +'<div class="t1"></div>'
                +'<div class="t2"></div>'
           +'</div>'
   );
</script>
```

**After using phpquery dom**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#div-id').append(
               '<div class="tool">'
                    +'<div class="t1"></script>
</div>'
                    +'<div class="t2"></div>'
               +'</div>'
       );
    </script>
```

An additional closing script tag is inserting the dom parser. Please help me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: what does `pq($script)->contents();` return?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question completely, it seems like it may be a bug but this is what I've found:

When I call `html()` like this: `$pq->html()` I get the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#div-id').append(
           '<div class="tool">'
                +'<div class="t1"/>'
                +'<div class="t2"/>'
           +'</div>'
   );
</script>
```

but when I do this:

```
foreach($pq->find('script') as $script){
    echo pq($script)->html();
}
```

I get the correct html

```
$('something else').append(
       '<div class="tool">'
            +'<div class="t1"></div>'
            +'<div class="t2"></div>'
       +'</div>'
);
```

I think its a bug, I'm going to report it. I'll let you know if I hear anything about this.

Comment: Hi, I think this is this bug: https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/issues/detail?id=212 . Did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I replace all script tag before load html to phpQuery. And after all operations, replace back scripts.

```
function str_replace_once($search, $replace, $text)
{
    $pos = strpos($text, $search);
    return $pos!==false ? substr_replace($text, $replace, $pos, strlen($search)) : $text;
}
function replaceScripts($js_atricle_html){
    preg_match_all('/<script.*?>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/', $js_atricle_html, $tmp);
    $scripts_array = $tmp[0]; 
    foreach ($scripts_array as $script_id=>$script_item){
        $js_atricle_html = self::str_replace_once($script_item, '<div class="script_item_num_'.$script_id.'"></div>', $js_atricle_html);
    }

    return array('content'=> $js_atricle_html, 'scripts_array'=>$scripts_array);
}
function unreplaceScripts($aticle_content, $scripts_array){
    preg_match_all('/<div class="script_item_num_(.*?)"><\/div>/', $aticle_content, $tmp);
    foreach ($tmp[1] as $script_num_item){
        $aticle_content = str_replace('<div class="script_item_num_'.$script_num_item.'"></div>', $scripts_array[$script_num_item], $aticle_content);
    }
    return $aticle_content;
}
```